# Como fazer consulta MYSQL e PHP usando um array como condição pro WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta no MYSQL que traz os emails que foram enviados. Esses emails estão na coluna emails, separados por virgula, como na tabela emailsenviados abaixo.

```
emailsenviados
IDenvio|emails
1      |a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com
2      |b@b.com
```

Aí preciso usar esses emails que estou pegando como array para fazer uma outra consulta que irá trazer o nome das pessoas desses emails, que estão na tabela users

```
ID|  nome  |email
1 | João   |a@a.com
2 | Maria  |b@b.com
3 | José   |c@c.com
```

Tem como eu fazer uma única consulta ou é em 2 mesmo? A princípio o que pensei foi fazer a primeira consulta e fazer um explode dos resultados para fazer uma segunda consulta, mas travei.

Minha consulta é feita assim:

```
$query=("SELECT id FROM emailsenviados WHERE IDenvio=1");
$db -> setQuery($query);
$incs = $db->loadResult();
```

e a segunda:

```
$query=("SELECT name FROM users WHERE >>AQUI SERIA A CONDIÇÃO PARA ENCONTRAR OS EMAILS<<");
$db -> setQuery($query);
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $row){
echo $nome.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça sua consulta assim:

```
$query=("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email IN (".$array_emails.")");
```

Onde a variável `$array_emails` deve ser na verdade uma string com todos e-mails separados por vírgula, exemplo:

> 'a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'

Comment: obrigado David, fiz isso, mas veio o bame em branco

Comment: O certo é vir um array de names né, um pra cada usuário que tenha e-mail dentro do array de e-mails. Deu algum erro?

Comment: não, fiz essa consulta no PHPMYADMIN primeiropara testar, troncando a variavel pelo valro, aí veio em branco sem erro: SELECT name FROM users WHERE email IN ("a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com")

Comment: testei agora ao invés do email, um campo de numero, aí funciona, talvez tenha que colocar alguma coisa por ser texto?

Comment: hmm, sim, os e-mails tem de estar entre aspas simples, vou corrigir na resposta

Comment: agora foi, fiz assim para colocar a variavel, existe outra forma mais simples?: $array_emails='"'.$array_emails.'"';
$array_emails=str_replace(',','","',$array_emails);

Comment: Esse código que você fez é uma boa saída.

Answer (score 2):

O MySQL tem uma função própria para isto, a `FIND_IN_SET`.

O `FIND_IN_SET( string1, string2 )` retorna verdadeiro caso o primeiro valor (`string1`) esteja contido numa lista separada por vírgulas passada em `string2`

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE FIND_IN_SET( email, emails )
```

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Vale notar que esta é a melhor saida caso o que vá variar seja o campo onde os emails estão listados. Para situações onde a lista é "fixa", a solução do David Alves de [usar uma concatenação do lado do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/315680/70) é boa.

Answer (score -2):

$query=("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email IN (".implode(",",$array_emails).")");

Fazendo assim, a variável $array_emails é convertida em uma string, com todos e-mails separados por vírgula, em uma única requisição

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Editei a resposta, explicando o que fiz